# Why is it enough to consider only closed paths around "holes" of the domain?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

If $D$ is an open connected domain and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, then $f$ has a holomorphic antiderivative iff. for every closed path $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow D$ the integral $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz = 0$. Now I read up the following, what to do in order to prove/disprove that a holomorphic $f$ has an antiderative: As it is impossible to consider every such closed path $\gamma$, it suffices to choose one such path $\gamma^*$ for each "hole" of the domain $D$ which revolves around this hole and show that for this path $\int_{\gamma^*}f(z)dz = 0$ holds.. I am trying to understand why and would be grateful for a hint or an explanation. I have been trying to apply winding numbers, but I did not arrive at any insights.

Comment: because if it didn't "go around" a hole (more precisely this would mean the path is homotopic to a point within $D$) then the integral $\int_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz$ would vanish (precisely because $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ and $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point). So, the only "troublesome" paths are those which loop around "holes of the domain".

Comment: Thank you! Is there also an explanation that uses winding numbers? I am not yet familiar with the concept of homotopy.